# Redirect User if Internal IP Address

Tags: php, ip-address

I am not familiar with PHP but I need to create a simple page to temporarily redirect internal users until a production problem is fixed.

If the user's IP address starts with `"10."`, `"192."`, or `"172."` then I need to redirect them to another server. If the user's IP address does not meet this criteria then I need to display a message telling the user the site is down for maintenance.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: For the record, not all addresses that start with `192.` or `172.` are internal/private.

Comment: @webbiedave While I know that is true, I don't know the exact rules which is disgraceful since my primary job role is to maintain IP networks - do you have a link to an authoritative source on what the rules actually are? I have seen/heard conflicting things, and all the official docs I have ever read don't actually explicitly set out address ranges reserved for internal usage, although I'm sure there must be some. For example, I know people tend to use `192.168.0.0/16` as internal, but `192.` is actually a C-class address so the rule *should* be more restrictive.

Comment: to expand from webbiedave, it's `192.168.*.*` and `172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255`

Comment: for the 'which numbers are private query' - reference http://whatismyipaddress.com/private-ip. To the OP, note too that all the answers - so far - are correct to your question, but incorrect to 'private/internal ip'

Comment: finally, wouldn't this be better handled in the webserver, not the php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$chunks = explode('.', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$whitelist = array(10, 192, 172);
$server = "http://example.com";
if(in_array($chunks[0], $whitelist))
{
    //redirect to another server
    header("Location: " . $server);
    die();
}
else
{
    //Show maintenance message
    die("The site is down for maintenance.");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) to see if the user's address ([`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php)) starts with `10.`, `192.`, or `172.`:

```
if(preg_match('/^(10|192|172)\./', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
{
    header('Location: http://example.com');
    die;
}
echo 'Site down for maintenance.';
```

Comment: What if the user is navigating to a site that uses public DNS, wouldn't this return the users public IP?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reliably identify a local ip address via the first octet of an IPv4 address. Luckily, PHP has taken care of all of this for us. I know the OP was asking only about IPv4, but this solution covers IPv6 and reserved addresses as well.

```
/**
 * Function returns true if IP Address is identified as private or reserved
 *
 * Uses REMOTE_ADDR, a reliable source as TCP handshake is required, most others can be spoofed
 *
 * FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE:
 *     Fails validation for the following private IPv4 ranges: 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 and 192.168.0.0/16.
 *     Fails validation for the IPv6 addresses starting with FD or FC.
 *
 * FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE:
 *     Fails validation for the following reserved IPv4 ranges: 0.0.0.0/8, 169.254.0.0/16, 192.0.2.0/24 and 224.0.0.0/4.
 *     This flag does not apply to IPv6 addresses.
 */
function isPrivateIp()
{
    return !filter_var($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE);
}

/*Using function to get OP desired result*/
if (isPrivateIp() === true) {
    $server = 'http://example.com';
    //redirect to another server
    header("Location: $server");
} else {
    //Show maintenance message
    echo 'The site is down for maintenance.';
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  // Settings
  $toRedirect = array (10, 172, 192);
  $redirectAddress = 'http://wherever.com/';
  $maintenanceMessage = 'The site is down for maintenance';

  // Split the IP address into octets
  list($oct1, $oct2, $oct3, $oct4) = explode('.', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

  // Send local clients to redirect address
  if (in_array($oct1, $toRedirect)) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect');
    header('Location: '.$redirectAddress);
  }

  // Exit with the maintenance message.
  // We can send this everyone in case the redirect fails
  exit($maintenanceMessage);
```

Comment: its $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] not $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDRESS'].

Answer (score 0):

Well,you can do this:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //get IP address
$toRedirect = array(10,192,172); 
$parts = explode('.', $ip); 
$id = $parts[0];
if(in_array($id, $toRedirect)) { 
  //do redirect
}
```